# How can I throttle this scroll event listener using rAF

Tags: javascript, scroll, event-listener, throttling, requestanimationframe

**Everything is working fine but I want to throttle this scroll event using requestAnimationFrame**

```
const header = document.querySelector("header#site-header");

let lastScroll = Math.round(window.scrollY);

function onScroll() {
    const currentScroll = Math.round(window.scrollY);

    if (currentScroll <= 50) return header.classList.remove("scrolled");
    if (currentScroll > lastScroll + 1) header.classList.add("scrolled");
    else if (currentScroll < lastScroll - 1) header.classList.remove("scrolled");

    lastScroll = currentScroll;

    // console.log("scrolled");
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
```

Comment: Check https://codepen.io/dcorb/pen/pgOKKw

Comment: There is no need to throttle a scroll event with rAF, both scroll events and rAF fire in the same ["update the rendering"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) step of the event-loop, the scroll event is already throttled to screen refresh rate. https://jsfiddle.net/aujqx28L/